# Removing mongodb document by its _id without using ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I've encountered an issue where I need to remove a MongoDB document by its `_id` without utilizing ObjectId in the PyMongo library. Typically, it seems that ObjectId needs to be imported and used for identifying documents for removal. However, I'm exploring whether there's an alternative method to achieve this without relying on `ObjectId`. As an example below is the document that i wish to remove

MongoDB Document

```js
{ _id: ObjectId("65fee1b40839f1f886ee94a9"), category: 'Cars' }
```

Python code with PyMongo

```py
import pymongo
from bson import ObjectId

document_id = ObjectId("65fee1b40839f1f886ee94a9")
result = collection.delete_one({"_id": document_id})

if result:
   return result.deleted_count
```

In This example i have used `ObectId` for document removal. Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to remove a document by its `_id` using PyMongo without explicitly using ObjectId?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you "not" want to use the ObjectId?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the `_id` as a string without needing to convert it to an ObjectID in _code_ ?

Comment: Hi @aneroid
Yes exactly.  something like : `collection.delete_one({"_id":  "65fee1b40839f1f886ee94a9"})`

Comment: @Jamie_D i was thinking that in some situations I may not be able to use bson in Python project. That's why I wanted to see if there is a way

Comment: I myself can't imagine a scenario where you wouldn't be able to use  `bson.objectid` in a Python project, but you could add a string value into your documents that matches the string conversion of the ObjectId in the document itself i.e: `document_id : "65fee1b40839f1f886ee94a9"`

Comment: I don't understand your antipathy towards `ObjectId`. Anyway, you might simply assign string values to the `_id` field so you can simply query it with strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a string to an ObjectID within the find query (or aggregation pipeline) with [`$toObjectId`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/):

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: ["$_id", { $toObjectId: "65fee1b40839f1f886ee94a9" }]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RS1ysdBXetH)

So your Python code should be:

```py
document_text_id: str = ...  # like "65fee1b40839f1f886ee94a9"
result = collection.delete_one({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": ["$_id", { "$toObjectId": document_text_id }]
  }
})
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Still trying to wrap my head around what scenerio would 'not' importing `bson.objectid` would be a game changer.